# Searchkick find entries by boolean field where clause in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, elasticsearch, searchkick

I have troubles querying in searchkick by boolean field only, I have tried many ways to query without luck

I have this model

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  searchkick

  # Indexed data
  def search_data
    {
      email: email,
      verified: verified,
      created_at: created_at,
      updated_at: updated_at,
    }
  end
end
```

I want to return with searchkick all users with `verified: true`, so I have run `User.reindex`

Then I have tried this queries:

```
results = User.search("*", where: { verified: true })
results.response
{"took"=>0, "timed_out"=>false, "_shards"=>{"total"=>1, "successful"=>1, "skipped"=>0, "failed"=>0}, "hits"=>{"total"=>{"value"=>0, "relation"=>"eq"}, "max_score"=>nil, "hits"=>[]}}

# Variations
results = User.search('*', :where=>{:verified=>[true]})
results = User.search('*', :where=>{:verified=>[1]})
results = User.search('*', :where=>{:verified=>["1"]})
results = User.search('*', :where=>{:verified=>["true"]})
```

I know I have users marked as verified in database but I cannot make it work in searchkick, I am missing something to search by boolean field?

Comment: Did you ever resolve this issue? I'm facing this myself and it has me stumped.

Comment: Yes, I have in my params {"verified": ["true"]} instead {"verified": "true"}, I was passing as array when I should be passing the value as it is.